# REPLACE function not working on SELECT using an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, inner-join

I can't get the REPLACE function to work on my SQL command shown here. I want it to take my search term (55512) and search for this in the field using the modified field from the regexp to remove all non-alphanumeric fields.

```
SELECT 
  `Customers`.`id` AS `Customers__id`,
  `Contact`.`id` AS `Contact__id`, 
  `Contact`.`customer_id` AS `Contact__customer_id`, 
  `Contact`.`full_name` AS `Contact__full_name`, 
  `Contact`.`phones` AS `Contact__phones`
FROM 
  `customers` `Customers` 
  INNER JOIN `contacts` `Contact` ON `Contact`.`id` = (`Customers`.`contact_id`) 
WHERE 
  REPLACE(
    `Contact`.`phones`, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", 
    ""
  ) LIKE '%55512%' 
LIMIT 
  20 OFFSET 0
```

So what I want to do is be able to search "55512" and have it match if the `Contact`.`phones` field contains "999-555-1212" or "(999) 555-1212". The `Contact`.`phones` field is stored as a JSON array in case this is relevant, but I would expect the above SQL command to remove all brackets, curly braces, etc and just search for the string.

When I do the above search in MySQL, it returns zero results, but there is a result that contains: [{"value":"999-555-1212","label":"Primary"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function does not work with regex, but attempts to match strings.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

- adopting [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function, that effectively uses regex:

```
WHERE 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    `Contact`.`phones`, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", 
    ""
  ) LIKE '%55512%'
```

- keeping the `REPLACE` function, but replacing dashes only with the empty string.

```
WHERE 
  REPLACE(
    `Contact`.`phones`, "-", 
    ""
  ) LIKE '%55512%'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/59sDREG19UWVuLa75rhn51/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE phones RLIKE '555-?12'
```

Would also work since the only extraneous characters would be a dash in one spot.

Both this and the answer from lemon will require a full table scan.  That is, either will be slow if the table is big.